# Disk Management with visual basic

Tags: vba, disk

I want to format a drive from visual basic application. Can anybody help me with it ?
I have tried **shFormat()**, but it is not completing my task. And If I Format my drive through **CMD**, it should be a background process for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a cmd from vba to execute the format command e.g.

```
Dim cmd_str As String
cmd_str = "cmd.exe /C format f:"
Call Shell(cmd_str, vbNormalFocus)
```

obviously the example above is for drive f:, change this as needed.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I make this process hidden i.e. the cmd should open as a background process.

Comment: Hi, try replacing the `vbNormalFocus` with `vbMinimizedNoFocus`, more info can be found here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/shell-function-HA001228906.aspx

Comment: Yeah I tried this but to execute the commands the user have to press **ENTER** manually , is there I can give the **ENTER** command in my code so that we can hide **cmd** and the command executes successfully.

Comment: Hi, you can bypass the checks if you use the /y parameter, so the cmd string would become: `cmd_str = "cmd.exe /C format f: /y"`, if you want a quick format use `cmd_str = "cmd.exe /C format f: /q /y"`